# Console doesn't show up in typescript intellisense

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I declared an api call to fetch data from my database and afterwards console.log stopped working

Intellisense: https://gyazo.com/4ae7f28093457eae2cf3e745a41a379f

The error that shows up: https://gyazo.com/89598de7ef3a8f04c87b65f4ff5d79b5

Comment: Are you trying to call `console.log()` in a class body? That's not allowed/possible/valid

Comment: First a piece of advice, next time put your code in the question, using the code feature from the editor here. checking code on images is not something most devs like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Given your partial screenshot, it seems the `console.log` that gives you the error is in the Class body.

If that is the case, that is the cause of your error.

You cannot have console.log on the class body, it needs to be inside a function.

Comment: Alright I am new to stack overflow I will keep that in mind